# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: for the bean categoryDAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My **Category.java** is:

```
 package shoppingbackend.dto;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity 
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "img_URL")
    private String imageURL;
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean active = true;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", imageURL=" + imageURL
                + ", active=" + active + "]";
    }

}
```

My **CategoryDAO.java** is:

```
package shoppingbackend.dao;
import java.util.List;
import shoppingbackend.dto.Category;
public interface CategoryDAO {
List<Category> list();

 Category getId(int id);
 boolean addCategory(Category category);
 boolean updateCategory(Category category);
 boolean deleteCategory(Category category);
}
```

My **CategoryDAOImpl** is:

```
 package shoppingbackend.daoimpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import shoppingbackend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import shoppingbackend.dto.Category;

@Repository("categoryDAO")
@Transactional
public class CategoryDAOimpl implements CategoryDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    //private static List<Category> categories= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<Category> list() {
        String selectActiveCategory="FROM Category WHERE active=:active";
        Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(selectActiveCategory);
        query.setParameter("active", true);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
    @Override
    public Category getId(int id) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Category.class,Integer.valueOf(id));

    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addCategory(Category category) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
        return true;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("from session catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;   
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean updateCategory(Category category) {
        try
        {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(category);
        return true;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("from session catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;   
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean deleteCategory(Category category) {
        category.setActive(false);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("inside try part");
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(category);
        return true;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("from session catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;   
        }
    }

}
```

and my **TestCase** is :

```
package shoppingbackend.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import shoppingbackend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import shoppingbackend.dto.Category;

public class CategoryTestCase {


    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
    private static CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
    private static Category category;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void init()
    {
        context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("shoppingbackend");
        context.refresh();
categoryDAO=(CategoryDAO)context.getBean("categoryDAO");

    }
    @Test
    public void testUpdateCategory()
    {
        category=categoryDAO.getId(17);
        category.setName("tubelight");
        System.out.println(category);
        assertEquals("successfully updated a category",true,categoryDAO.updateCategory(category));
    }

}
```

my **hibernate config** file is:

```
package shoppingbackend.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
//mport org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="{shoppingbackend.dto}")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    private static final String DATABASE_URL="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/onlineshopping";
    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER="org.h2.Driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_DIALECT="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
    private static final String DATABASE_USERNAME="sid";
    private static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD="";

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource dataSource =new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;

    }
    //always take care of the hibernate version u are using m using 5 so my Builder will also be of 5
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder= new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("shoppingbackend.dto");

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",DATABASE_DIALECT);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql","true");

        return properties;

    }



    @Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager= new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
return  hibernateTransactionManager;
}
}
```

and my **pom.xml** is:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>onlineshopping</groupId>
  <artifactId>onlineshopping</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
  <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>
  <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>5.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

  <!-- adding backend here -->
<!--   the below idea failed maybe due to the war packaging  -->
 <!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>shoppingbackend</groupId>
  <artifactId>shoppingbackend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency> -->
   <!-- adding backend here -->

   <!-- h2 database  -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.196</version>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please help. I am stuck in it since many days and I am completely new to hibernate.

The whole console error is :

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in
>   shoppingbackend.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error
>   activating Bean Validation integration 15.46.11.107
>   o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

If you use hibernate-validator you have to remove the javax.validation dependency.

For more info:
[Project set up](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: Do you have the causedBy of the excepción? Maybe there you can find more info

Comment: sorry, i don't seem to have it .. i was just trying to run the test case and i faced the error i mentioned above..

Comment: I was reading about @bean on methods, and i dont know if having a parameter in a Bean method is ok. Try removing the parameter datasource in the getsessionfactory. https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/10/spring-configuration-and-injecting-bean.html?m=1

Comment: Is it  any kind of jar conflict... but it was working fine few days ago with the same configuration...anyone please help..

Comment: See what you changed in your vcs 

Comment: you were right @Lucas there is a conflict between hibernate-validator and the validation api but i  also tried their latest versions but that also didn't work , now the problem is how to solve the conflict...i have surfed enough but found nothing regarding to solve my problem..

Comment: If you use only javax validator without hibernate validator?

Comment: no that raises some other errors because hibernate validator requires validation api for validation stuff...hahahha funny situation

Comment: hibernate validator is the only problem but its strange that removing it from one project does the work and removing it from another doesn't change the error at all..

Answer (score 0):

replaced this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

by this:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and everything is working as before .... i don't know why the 6.0.2 version was working fine earlier ....